# Is there any technology that could automatically generate the semantic level features needed for programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, semantic-analysis

In LSP Server, To provide semantic-level language support capabilities, additional code would need to be written manually to implement them.Is there any technology that could automatically generate the semantic level features needed for programming language?